# aws glue tables created by athena are read twice by emr spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue, amazon-athena

When I create a table in athena with CTAS syntax (example below), tables are registered to glue in a way that when I read the same table on an EMR cluster with (py)spark, every partition is read twice, but when I read it with athena, it is alright. When I create a table through spark with `write.saveAsTable` syntax, it's registered to glue properly and this table is read properly with spark and with athena.

I didn't find anything in the spark/athena/glue documentation about this. After some trial and errors I found out that there is a glue table property that is set by spark and not set by athena: `spark.sql.sources.provider='parquet'`. When I set this manually on tables created via athena, spark will read it properly. But this feels like an ugly workaround and I would like to understand what's happening in the background. And I didn't find anything about this table property.

Athena create table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE {database}.{table}
WITH (format = 'Parquet',
      parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
      external_location = '{s3path}')
AS SELECT
```

Comment: have you tried setting this property immediately after you ran CTAS with ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ('property_name' = 'property_value' [ , ... ]) in Athena?

Comment: No I didn't, but my workaround is similar using `awswrangler` lib.
My main concern is that I don't really understand what this table property means and whether this can be considered as a proper solution (and later emr/spark versions will handle the same way as current).

Comment: try an explain plan on this table using pyspark to see where it is reading the details twice by applying a filter on partition column which will tell you the location of the partitions it is reading the data from

Comment: I don't really understand the output of explain's physical plan, but here it is (only the relevant part): `Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3:/path, s3://path], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ...` and the input path is duplicated at `Location`

Comment: Can you update the full plan in the question?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. If you mean the full physical plan, I don't know how to access it other than calling `df.explain(extended=True)`, but it gives me only this truncated version of the physical plan.